# I don't have a 503 header but Google displays "Site under maintenance". How to remove it?

Tags: php, http-status-code-503, maintenance-mode

I was working on the website and it displayed a maintenance page, which didn't contain a 503 header...

```
header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
header("Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
header("Retry-After: 3600");
```

Now, when searching for my site on Google it displays the title of the maintenance page, which is "SITENAME: Site under maintenance". I think, this probably because Google indexed my site during the maintenance?!?

How can I remove it as soon as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickest way is to register the site under webmaster tools and request a removal then a crawl on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Just be patient, Google will re-index it.